# How redirect pages with apache2 when site is under maintenance

Tags: web-services, apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

i can't understand how redirect pages when the site is under construction, i search a lot on the the web, and i found that some people use the `.htaccess` but this is what apache2 configuration said:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down
>   your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a
>   .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the
>   same effect with better performance.

so, if suggest me avoid using `.htacces` what i have to use? i can't understand how use the `Directory` block if it's better...someone can help me? thanks

Comment: Look this website https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html